# How to prevent users from editing home page in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

[Wikipedia's front page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) can't be edited.

Can such a front page also be made with MediaWiki, so the users can't edit it?

Comment: Seems like it can be edited just fine: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Main_Page&action=edit

Comment: You can view the source, but notice there is no Save button.

Comment: You can hit the edit button, but you can't actually change it unless you're an administrator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you need to [protect it](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aProtecting_and_unprotecting_pages) so that it can only be edited by administrators:

> You can designate a page as a protected page by clicking the 'Protect
>   page' tab ('protect' in the drop-down menu in Vector), and supplying a
>   comment (a brief textual description of why you are protecting the
>   page).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure your IIS/Apache/WebServer so that it points to an index file that is completely separate from MediaWiki. Throw in a text input and submit button for the search and have it post to MediaWiki's search. This way, you've got a static home page that users cannot edit with a functional search.

Comment: I think protecting the page is a much better solution.